# ArcGIS shared update group

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map, shared-hosting

I would like to create a shared update group on ArcGIS, however, the "what items in the group can members update?" question is missing and I can´t, therefore, tag it. The questionnaire just ends after "Who can contribute content?" (s. picture). Has this option been removed?
[image: end of questionaire]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is now embedded in the group designation settings:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, though this seems to be only availeable for default administrators. :(

Comment: Unfortunately yes, only for default admins.